# Upload data from DICOM files in Torchvision Model

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, pydicom, medical-imaging

I'm sorry if the question is too basic, but I am just getting started with PyTorch (and Python).

I was trying to follow step by step the instructions here:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

However,I am working with have some DICOM files, that I kept into two directories (CANCER/NOCANCER). I split them with split-folders, to have it structured to be used with the ImageFolder dataset (as done in the tutorial).

I am aware that I only need to load the pixel_arrays extracted from the DICOM files, and I wrote some helper functions to:

1. read all paths of the .dcm files;
2. read them and extract the pixel_array;
3. do a little preprocessing.
   Here are the outlines of the helper functions:

```
import os
import pydicom
import cv2
import numpy as np 
   
   
def createListFiles(dirName):
   print("Fetching all the files in the data directory...")
   lstFilesDCM =[]
   for root, dir, fileList in os.walk(dirName):
       for filename in fileList:
            if ".dcm" in filename.lower():
               lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join( root , filename))
   return lstFilesDCM
   
def castHeight(list):
   lstHeight = []
   min_height = 0        
   for filenameDCM in list:
       readfile = pydicom.read_file(filenameDCM)
       lstHeight.append(readfile.pixel_array.shape[0])
       min_height = np.min(lstHeight)   
   return  min_height
   
   
def castWidth(list):
   lstWidth = []
   min_Width = 0
   for filenameDCM in list:
       readfile = pydicom.read_file(filenameDCM)
       lstWidth.append(readfile.pixel_array.shape[1])
       min_Width = np.min(lstWidth)   
   return  min_Width
  
   
def Preproc1(listDCM):
   new_height, new_width = castHeight(listDCM), castWidth(listDCM)
   ConstPixelDims = (len(listDCM), int(new_height), int(new_width)) 
       
   ArrayDCM = np.zeros(ConstPixelDims, dtype=np.float32)
       
   ## loop through all the DICOM files
   for filenameDCM in listDCM:    
       ## read the file
       ds = pydicom.read_file(filenameDCM)
           
       mx0 = ds.pixel_array
           
       ## Standardisation 
       imgb = mx0.astype('float32')
       imgb_stand = (imgb - imgb.mean(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)) / imgb.std(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
           
       ## Normalisation 
       imgb_norm = cv2.normalize(imgb_stand, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)        
           
       ## we make sure that data is saved as a data_array as a numpy array
       data = np.array(imgb_norm)
   
   
       ## we save it into ArrayDicom and resize it based 'ConstPixelDims' 
       ArrayDCM[listDCM.index(filenameDCM), :, :] =  cv2.resize(data, (int(new_width), int(new_height)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
       
   return ArrayDCM
```

So, now, how do I tell the dataloader to load the data, considering the structure it's in for labelling purposes, but only after doing this extraction and preprocessing on it?
I'm referencing the "Loading data" part of the tutorial in the documentation, that goes:

```
# Create training and validation datasets
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
# Create training and validation dataloaders
dataloaders_dict = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

If it makes any sense, is it possible to do something on the lines of

```
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(Preproc1(os.path.join(data_dir, x)), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

?

Also, another question I have is: is it worth to do a normalisation step in my preprocessing when the tutorial suggests to do a transforms.Normalize ?

I'm really sorry this sounds so vague, I've been trying to solve this for weeks now, but I can't manage.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will be better off implementing your own [custom `Dataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574689/1714410).
And indeed, I think it would be better deferring normalization and other stuff to the transformations applied just before reading the images for the model.

Comment: Any particular reason for deferring normalization?
I'll try implementing my own Dataset, it just throws me off following the tutorial step by step, which is about all I can do now. I'll learn, somehow.

Comment: This will help you in normalization
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347141/11170350