# Pytorch load data in mini batches

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, satellite-image, pytorch-dataloader

I have a folder of images as such

```
Images
|
|__img1
|   |__img1_b01.tiff
|   |__img1_b02.tiff
|   |__img1_b03.tiff
|   |__img1_b04.tiff
|   |__img1_b05.tiff
|  
|__img2
|   |__img2_b02.tiff
|   |__img2_b02.tiff
|   |__img2_b03.tiff
|   |__img2_b04.tiff
|   |__img2_b05.tiff
|
|.. img1000
```

Each folder represents an image.
Each file in the folders represents a band channel of the image.

Hence each image would have a

I am stuck writting the pytorch custom dataloader to load in batches of 64

So I could have Feature batch shape: torch.Size([64,5, 256, 256])

I have tried the following code

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils import data

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = Images/, 
            transform = transforms.ToTensor())

loader = data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = 64, shuffle = True)
```

But it is not giving the results I want which is `Feature batch shape: torch.Size([64, 5, 256, 256])`

Comment: This is not a dataloader issue but a dataset issue. You won't manage to achieve what you need here with `ImageFolder`, its documentation (https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#imagefolder) is pretty explicit about the required folder structure and it is different from yours. You need to implement the dataset class yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `datasets.ImageFolder` will make PyTorch treat each "band" image independently and treat the folder names (e.g., `img1`, `img2`...) as "class labels".
In order to load 5 image files as different bands/channels of the *same* image, you'll need to write your own [custom `Dataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574689/1714410).

This custom `Dataset` may look something like this:

```py
import torch
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class MultiBandDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, root, num_bands):
    self.root = root
    self.num_bands = num_bands
    self.imgs = os.listdir(root)  # all `imgNN` folders
     
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.imgs)  # number of images = number of subfolders

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    multi_band = []
    # get the subfolder
    subf = os.path.join(self.root, self.imgs[index])
    for band in range(self.num_bands):
      b = Image.open(os.path.join(subf, f'{self.imgs[index]}_b{band+1:02d}.tiff')).convert("F")  # make sure you are reading a single channel from each image. you need to verify this part.
      multi_band.append(np.array(b).astype(np.float32)[None,...])  # add singleton channel dimension
    return np.concatenate(numti_band, axis=0)
```

Note that you would probably need to re-implement augmentations as well.

Comment: what is this supposed to be [None,...] `multi_band.append(np.array(b).astype(np.float32)[None,...])`  @shai