# how to load two dataset images simultaneously for train two streams(Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

i need load identical two dataset suppose one dataset has RGB images and another dataset contain same image with different processed(grey images)  with same order same size,

```
datasetA=[1.jpg,2.jpg,..........n.jpg] // RGB
datasetA=[g1.jpg,g2.jpg,..........gn.jpg] //grey
```

so I need to feed the same order images to two independent networks using DataLoader with random_split, so how to use

```
rgb = datasets.ImageFolder(rgb images)
grey = datasets.ImageFolder(gray images)

train_data1, test_data = random_split(rgb, [train_data, test_data])
train_data2, test_data = random_split(grey, [train_data, test_data])

train_loader1 = DataLoader(train_data1, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
train_loader2 = DataLoader(train_data2, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

so need to load same order images touple like (1.jpg,g1.jpg) for train both network independantly

and how to use

```
trainiter1 = iter(train_loader1)
features, labels = next(trainiter)
```

please explain process

Answer (score 1):

I think he easiest way to go about this is to construct a [custom `Dataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574689/1714410) that handles both:

```py
class JointImageDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, args_rgb_dict, args_grey_dict):
    # construct the two individual datasets
    self.rgb_dataset = ImageFolder(**args_rgb_dict)
    self.grey_dataset = ImageFolder(**args_grey_dict)

  def __len__(self):
    return min(len(self.rgb_dataset), len(selg.grey_dataset))

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    rgb_x, rgb_y = self.rgb_dataset[index]
    grey_x, grey_y = self.grey_dataset[index]
    return rgb_x, grey_x, rgb_y, grey_y
```

Now you can construct a *single* `DataLoader` from the `JoindImageDataset` and iterate over the joint batches:

```py
joint_data = JoindImageDataset(...)
train_loader = DataLoader(joint_data, batch_size=...)
for rgb_batch, grey_batch, rgb_ys, grey_ys in train_loader:
  # do your stuff here...
```

Comment: im getting 
OSError: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. Error loading "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: @Lanka this looks like a new issue. either edit your question to reflect this error (if it's related), or ask a new one, clearly indicating what you did and what part of the code issued this error.