# Training a CNN for image classification using two grey-scale bands together as input

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, concatenation, pytorch-dataloader

I want to train a CNN for image classification, with three classes, but using two grey-scale bands together. Grey-scale images are all the same shape: `(20, 20)`, and the image file numbering and labeling are identical. i.e. if image_1.png from the first band is class 2, then image_1.png from the second band is also class 2, etc. And the number of images for each band is equal.

I have tried applying `ConcatDataset()`, and that works fine, but I get, of course, a DataLoader with all the first band and all the second band as single band input tensors: each iteration has shape `(batch_size, 1, 20, 20)`. What I want is a DataLoader with items of shape `(batch_size, 2, 20, 20)`

How would I do this? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247325/how-to-load-two-dataset-images-simultaneously-for-train-two-streamspytorch), but it's not clear to me how to combine the bands.

Thanks

Comment: You got that because `ConcatDataset` consider the input two dataset so the output I think would be `2*batch_size, 1, 20, 20`. In your case I think you could implement  subclassing `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and overwritte the `__getitem__()` and `__len__()` method. In that way you can pre-process the images (concatenate as you wish) in the `__getitem__()` call made by the `DataLoader`.

Comment: @StandardIO: Thanks. So when you say "preprocess the images" I guess you mean to read them into numpy arrays, then stack, and return as an ndarray? That would be in the `__getitem__()` function?

Comment: Yes, in the  link you posted they did the same approach. I could modify the code to your needs but I don't know how you are reading the images. Also, here you can find tuturial how it works and maybe do it by yourself [pytorch tuturial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html)